# String keys to human readable text in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to transform various message keys to a human readable text in a template, for example:

```
database_skill => "Database Skill"
experience_3_4 => "3 to 4 years of experience"
```

I tried with internationalization but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. A `.po` file is generated for `en-us`, I add the "translation" but I can not see it in the template once I use it:

```
msgid "database_skills"
msgstr "Database Skills"
```

Template:

```
{% load i18n %}
Translated: {% translate "database_skills" %} => this still shows "database_skills"
```

My settings:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "app/locale"),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', 'English'),
)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I go for another approach?

Edit: Add locale directory structure

```
project_root/app/locale/en-us/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

Comment: Did you compile the messages ? Also, show your locale structure

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane, yes I did. You mean the directory structure? If yes I will update the question with that.

Comment: Yes. Directory structure.

Comment: I added it to the question, bu here it is as well `project_root/app/locale/en-us/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is annoying, turns out the directory for my language should have been called `en_US` with an underscore and capital letters for the country code, even tho the language code itself is `en-us` with a dash and lowercase.
Everything works fine now.